# Using gradient descent in python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am trying to implement gradient descent that will match my closed form solution. The one thing that has not been able to be resolved is that my theta will either not go through with my prediction due to error

```
ValueError: shapes (400,2) and (400,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

or in my theta formula the error operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (2,400). I was wondering if this because of the initialization of theta being wrong whether I just make an array or using the zeros function.

```
import numpy as num
import pandas 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot


#gradient descent solution
def gradient_descent(X, y, theta, alpha, iterations):
   
    
    
    for iteration in range(iterations):
        hypothesis = X.dot(theta)
        print(hypothesis)
        loss = hypothesis-y
        gradient = X.T.dot(loss)/m
        theta = theta - alpha*gradient
        

    return theta

ones = num.ones((x.shape[0], 1))
X = num.hstack((x,ones))
m=x.shape[0]
theta=num.array([0,0])
iterations =1500
alpha = 0.1

#calling gradient descent function 
t = gradient_descent(X,y,theta,alpha,iterations)

print(t)
```

Comment: Please take care to tag appropriately, and not to bury the error message in the text (edited).

Comment: You need to also post a sample of your `x` and `y` that causes the same issue.